# Using Request Header and Body information for Ajax query with scrapy

Tags: ajax, scrapy

I am scraping the following web site https://www2.woolworthsonline.com.au
My first step is to get a list of product categories, which I can do.

Then I need to get sub-categories. The sub-categories seem to be dynamically generated. I have set up what I thought to be the right header and body information for the request and a small test call-back to see if the request is working correctly. My code never gets to the callback, so presumably there is something wrong with the request

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Get links to the categories
    categories_links = response.xpath('//a[@class="navigation-link"]').re(r'href="(\S+)"')
    for link in categories_links:
    # Generate and yield a request for the sub-categories

        get_request_headers = dict()
        get_request_headers['Accept'] = 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01'
        get_request_headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, sdch'
        get_request_headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
        get_request_headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'

        get_request_body = urllib.urlencode(
                                            {'_mode' : 'ajax',
                                             '_ajaxsource' : 'navigation-panel',
                                             '_referrer' : link,
                                             '_bannerViews' : '6064',
                                             '_' : '1429428492880'}
                                            )

        url_link = 'https://www2.woolworthsonline.com.au'+link
        yield Request(url=url_link, callback=self.subcategories, headers = get_request_headers, method='POST', body = get_request_body, meta={'category_link' : link} )

    return

def subcategories(self, response):
    print "sub-categories test: ", response.url
    return
```

Comment: try to add cookie in request

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
BASE_URL = 'https://www2.woolworthsonline.com.au'


def parse(self, response):
    categories = response.xpath(
        '//a[@class="navigation-link"]/@href').extract()
    for link in categories:
        yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + link, callback=parse_subcategory)


def parse_subcategory(self, response):
    sub_categories = response.xpath(
        '//li[@class="navigation-node navigation-category  selected"]/ul/li/span/a/@href').extract()
    for link in sub_categories:
        yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + link, callback=parse_products)


def parse_products(self, response):
    # here you will get the list of products based on the subcategory
    # extract the product details here
```

- First we extract the category list from the start-url in `parse` function
- Then give request to extracted `category-url` ( we have to provide `BASE_URL` along with the extracted `category-url`, since that urls are given as relative urls not the absolute one)
- In the `callback function` (here `parse_subcategory`) we can get the response of each `category-url`
- Likewise we are doing the same thing for sub-categories also
- Finally extract the product details